# frameskipping in Pygame?

Tags: pygame, time

I am struggling to find a solution on how to skip frames and keep the game at a constant pace, I had tried using

```python
self.LAST_FRAME = self.ELAPSED_TIME - self.LAST_FRAME
time.sleep((1 / average_fps) - self.LAST_FRAME * 1000)
```

but then later found [ConstantGameSpeed](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/ConstantGameSpeed) but my brain just couldn't process on how to use the library, **anyone can just show me a solution** or **just show me how to use the library**

Comment: did you try `pygame.time.Clock().tick(25)` to keep 25 frames per second? [pygame.time](https://web.archive.org/web/20220120173924/https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html)

Comment: when the fps slows down the whole game slows down

Comment: if you use constant values to calculate positions in every frame then it will slow down with slower FPS. You should use time to calculate positions. And all games use time to calculate postions. `tick = pygame.time.Clock().tick(25)` should give time between frames and this time you should use to calculate positions. something like `speed_x * tick`, `speed_y * tick`. OR `speed_x * self.LAST_FRAME` `speed_y * self.LAST_FRAME`

Comment: actually you should use 2 functions: 
1. paint your game (only drawing no movement or animation)
2. update your game (calculate new positions, animations, gamelogic, usercontrols, etc)

The trick is not to call both functions alternating, but calling "update" 60 times per second *fixed* and "paint" as often as possible (not faster than 60FPS)
In this way your controls are always reactive and everything moves the same time even if your FPS get slower.
This only works if "update" is faster than "paint"